# I'm trying to make the input entered from the textfield the new name of my list when the save button is pressed, but it didn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't find how to get user input and update my name on the TodoListView
All code below . Nothing much but i can't make it.
(in my model i have id=UUID and name=String)

ChangeTodoView(On this view i try to get users input and change the value)

```
struct ChangeTodoView: View {
@State var not: String
@ObservedObject var todoVM = TodoListViewModel()
init(not: String){
    self.not = not
}

var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Enter Your Note")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            Spacer(minLength: 30)
            Form {
                TextEditor(text: $not)
                        Button(action: {
                           // todoVM.items[1] = not
                            //
                            
                            todoVM.rename(indexSet: , not: not)
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Save")
                        }).disabled(not.isEmpty)
                    }
            
        }            
}
```

TodoListView(on this page i open ChangeTodoView)

```
struct ToDoListView: View {
@ObservedObject var todoVM = TodoListViewModel()
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List{
            ForEach(todoVM.items){item in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ChangeTodoView(not: ""),
                        label : {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                
                    }            
            }
        .navigationTitle("Todo App")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                    EditButton()
                    Button {
                        todoVM.addItem()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    
   
    }
}
```

TodoListViewModel(rename function is my updating function. i try to get index and change that name to new name )

```
class TodoListViewModel: ObservableObject{
@Published var items = [Item(id: UUID(), name: "note1"), Item(id: UUID(), name: "note2"), Item(id: UUID(), name: "note3")]

init(){
    
    
}
func rename(indexSet: IndexSet, not: String) -> String{
    for index in indexSet{
        items[index].name = not
    }
    return not
    
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to make this code compile, and cut out the unnecessary code like the delete, move etc.

Comment: Thanks to advice this is my first question but next time i will do that :)

Comment: You can edit the question and fix the errors. You will most likely not get an answer unless you do.

Comment: updated now i hope it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important change that has to happen is that you have to pass a *single instance* of the `TodoListViewModel` between your views. Right now, because you're creating a second instance of it in `ChangeTodoView`, your changes never get back to the original parent view (which, again, has a different instance of the view model).

I had to make a couple of other changes to your code because there was information left out about your indexSet and how you were deriving that, but that's all secondary to the issue of the *single instance* of the view model (so, make sure your only use `TodoListViewModel()` *once*).

```
struct Item : Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
}

class TodoListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var items = [Item(id: UUID(), name: "note1"), Item(id: UUID(), name: "note2"), Item(id: UUID(), name: "note3")]
    func rename(id: UUID, not: String) {
        items = items.map { item -> Item in
            if item.id == id {
                var copy = item
                copy.name = not
                return copy
            } else {
                return item
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ToDoListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var todoVM = TodoListViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(todoVM.items){ item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ChangeTodoView(id: item.id, not: "", todoVM: todoVM), //<-- pass the instance
                        label : {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChangeTodoView: View {
    var id: UUID
    @State var not : String
    @ObservedObject var todoVM : TodoListViewModel //<-- Passed from parent view
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Enter Your Note")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            Spacer(minLength: 30)
            Form {
                TextEditor(text: $not)
                Button(action: {
                    todoVM.rename(id: id, not: not)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }).disabled(not.isEmpty)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it works for me :) Would it be better for me to create another vm for this ChangeTodoView?

Comment: Not necessarily. But, as your app grows and you design your persistence and things like that, you may decide it's better to arrange things differently.